# compile npapi plugin in Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, firefox, npapi

I only have ssh access to a Mac OSX 10.6 computer, so, Xcode is out of scope. Currently, I have trouble to figure out the right format of g++ output: do I need to append -shared and -fPIC, or -dynamiclib or other magic flag in order to get a firefox recognizable binary?

Comment: I think it is a design flaw. A correct answer should be automatically up-voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following:

- `-dynamiclib`
- `-fPIC`
- `-arch foo` as needed
- `-DXP_MAC=1`, `-DXP_MACOSX=1` etc.
- `-framework UsedFrameWork` as needed
- `-mmacosx-version-min=10.x` if needed

Also remember to put it all in a plugin bundle and to include a suitable [plist](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/plugin/sdk/samples/basic/mac/Info.plist).

Comment: thanks! I am relatively new to mac plugin (or mac development in general), can you refer me some links that explain what bundle is here?

Comment: Bundles are a directory structure in that your binary and related resources reside - Apples documentation explains it in some detail: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: By the way, if you haven't found it yet, Apple also has a browser-plugin-in overview: http://www.devworld.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/WebKit_PluginProgTopic/WebKitPluginTopics.html

Answer (score 0):

It should also be noted that you can compile something using xcode from the command line using xcodebuild.